# building conway's game of life for iPad

Tags: ipad, class, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to build conway's game of life in Xcode (for the iPad), but I can't seem to figure out how to make it reasonably sized.  As it is now its 10*10 and took quite a while to put together.  I don't even think this works right.

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect {
if (first == false) {
     first = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
            ask[x][y] = false;

        }
    }
   // ask[7][7] = true;
    ask[3][9] = true;
    ask[3][8] = true;
    ask[4][9] = true;
    ask[3][7] = true;
    ask[5][2] = true;
    ask[1][4] = true;
    ask[2][3] = true;
    ask[1][3] = true;
    ask[4][2] = true;
}



for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
        counter1 = 0;
        if((ask[x][y]) == true){

            if(ask[x][y+1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x][y-1] == true){
                    counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x-1][y-1] == true){
                    counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x-1][y+1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if ((ask[x-1][y] = true)){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x+1][y+1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x+1][y] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x+1][y-1] == true) {
                counter1+= 1;
            }

            if (counter1 < 2){
                ask[x][y] = false;
            }else if (counter1 > 3){
                ask[x][y] = false;
            }
        }else if (ask[x][y] == false){

            if(ask[x][y-1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x][y+1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
             if ((ask[x-1][y] = true)){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x-1][y-1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x-1][y+1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x+1][y+1] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x+1][y] == true){
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if(ask[x+1][y-1] == true) {
                counter1+= 1;
            }
            if (counter1 == 3) {
                ask[x][y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (ask[0][0] == false) {
    one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[0][1] == false) {
    two = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    two = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[0][2] == false) {
    three = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    three = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[0][3] == false) {
    four = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    four = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[0][4] == false) {
    five = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    five = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[0][5] == false) {
    six = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    six = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[0][6] == false) {
    seven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[0][7] == false) {
    eight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[0][8] == false) {
    nine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    nine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[0][9] == false) {
    ten = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ten = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][0] == false) {
    eleven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eleven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][1] == false) {
    twelve = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twelve = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][2] == false) {
    thirteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][3] == false) {
    fourteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fourteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[1][4] == false) {
    fifteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[1][5] == false) {
    sixteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][6] == false) {
    seventeen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventeen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][7] == false) {
    eighteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][8] == false) {
    nineteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    nineteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[1][9] == false) {
    twenty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twenty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][0] == false) {
    twentyone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentyone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][1] == false) {
    twentytwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentytwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][2] == false) {
    twentythree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentythree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][3] == false) {
    twentyfour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentyfour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][4] == false) {
    twentyfive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentyfive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][5] == false) {
    twentysix = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentysix = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][6] == false) {
    twentyseven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentyseven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][7] == false) {
    twentyeight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentyeight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][8] == false) {
    twentynine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    twentynine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[2][9] == false) {
    thirty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[3][0] == false) {
    thirtyone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtyone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][1] == false) {
    thirtytwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtytwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][2] == false) {
    thirtythree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtythree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][3] == false) {
    thirtyfour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtyfour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][4] == false) {
    thirtyfive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtyfive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][5] == false) {
    thirtysix = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtysix = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][6] == false) {
    thirtyseven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtyseven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][7] == false) {
    thirtyeight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtyeight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][8] == false) {
    thirtynine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    thirtynine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[3][9] == false) {
    forty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[4][0] == false) {
    forty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][1] == false) {
    forty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][2] == false) {
    forty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][3] == false) {
    forty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][4] == false) {
    forty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][5] == false) {
    forty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][6] == false) {
    forty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][7] == false) {
    forty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][8] == false) {
    forty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    forty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[4][9] == false) {
    fifty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][0] == false) {
    fifty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][1] == false) {
    fifty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][2] == false) {
    fifty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][3] == false) {
    fifty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][4] == false) {
    fifty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][5] == false) {
    fifty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][6] == false) {
    fifty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][7] == false) {
    fifty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][8] == false) {
    fifty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    fifty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[5][9] == false) {
    sixty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][0] == false) {
    sixty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][1] == false) {
    sixty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][2] == false) {
    sixty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][3] == false) {
    sixty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][4] == false) {
    sixty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][5] == false) {
    sixty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][6] == false) {
    sixty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][7] == false) {
    sixty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][8] == false) {
    sixty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    sixty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[6][9] == false) {
    seventy = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}


if (ask[7][0] == false) {
    seventy1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][1] == false) {
    seventy2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][2] == false) {
    seventy3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][3] == false) {
    seventy4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][4] == false) {
    seventy5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][5] == false) {
    seventy6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][6] == false) {
    seventy7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][7] == false) {
    seventy8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][8] == false) {
    seventy9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    seventy9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[7][9] == false) {
    eighty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}

if (ask[8][0] == false) {
    eighty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][1] == false) {
    eighty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][2] == false) {
    eighty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][3] == false) {
    eighty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][4] == false) {
    eighty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][5] == false) {
    eighty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][6] == false) {
    eighty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][7] == false) {
    eighty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][8] == false) {
    eighty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    eighty9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[8][9] == false) {
    ninety = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}


if (ask[9][0] == false) {
    ninety1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][1] == false) {
    ninety2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][2] == false) {
    ninety3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][3] == false) {
    ninety4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][4] == false) {
    ninety5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][5] == false) {
    ninety6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][6] == false) {
    ninety7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][7] == false) {
    ninety8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][8] == false) {
    ninety9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    ninety9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}
if (ask[9][9] == false) {
    hundred = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
}else{
    hundred = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
}



[one drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 0)];
[two drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 25)];
[three drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 50)];
[four drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 75)];
[five drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[six drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 125)];
[seven drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 150)];
[eight drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 175)];
[nine drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200)];
[ten drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 225)];


[eleven drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 0)];
[twelve drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 25)];
[thirteen drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 50)];
[fourteen drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 75)];
[fifteen drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 100)];

[sixteen drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 125)];
[seventeen drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 150)];
[eighteen drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 175)];
[nineteen drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 200)];
[twenty drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(125, 225)];


[twentyone drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 0)];
[twentytwo drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 25)];
[twentythree drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 50)];
[twentyfour drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 75)];
[twentyfive drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 100)];
[twentysix drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 125)];
[twentyseven drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)];
[twentyeight drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 175)];
[twentynine drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 200)];
[thirty drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 225)];



[thirtyone drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 0)];
[thirtytwo drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 25)];
[thirtythree drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 50)];
[thirtyfour drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 75)];
[thirtyfive drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 100)];
[thirtysix drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 125)];
[thirtyseven drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 150)];
[thirtyeight drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 175)];
[thirtynine drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 200)];
[forty drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(175, 225)];

[forty1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 0)];
[forty2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 25)];
[forty3 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 50)];
[forty4 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 75)];
[forty5 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
[forty6 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 125)];
[forty7 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 150)];
[forty8 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 175)];
[forty9 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
[fifty drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 225)];


[fifty1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 0)];
[fifty2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 25)];
[fifty3 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 50)];
[fifty4 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 75)];
[fifty5 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 100)];
[fifty6 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 125)];
[fifty7 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 150)];
[fifty8 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 175)];
[fifty9 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 200)];
[sixty drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(225, 225)];

[sixty1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 0)];
[sixty2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 25)];
[sixty3 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 50)];
[sixty4 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 75)];
[sixty5 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 100)];
[sixty6 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 125)];
[sixty7 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 150)];
[sixty8 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 175)];
[sixty9 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 200)];
[seventy drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 225)];

[seventy1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 0)];
[seventy2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 25)];
[seventy3 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 50)];
[seventy4 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 75)];
[seventy5 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 100)];
[seventy6 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 125)];
[seventy7 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 150)];
[seventy8 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 175)];
[seventy9 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 200)];
[eighty drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(275, 225)];


[eighty1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 0)];
[eighty2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 25)];
[eighty3 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 50)];
[eighty4 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 75)];
[eighty5 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 100)];
[eighty6 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 125)];
[eighty7 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 150)];
[eighty8 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 175)];
[eighty9 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 200)];
[ninety drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(300, 225)];

[ninety1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 0)];
[ninety2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 25)];
[ninety3 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 50)];
[ninety4 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 75)];
[ninety5 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 100)];
[ninety6 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 125)];
[ninety7 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 150)];
[ninety8 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 175)];
[ninety9 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 200)];
[hundred drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(325, 225)];}
```

-(void) dealloc {

}

@end

Comment: http://golly.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, several ideas. :D

http://www.oliverfoggin.com/game-of-life/

The way I would approach building it (if I was to start again), would be to work exclusively on a class (or collection of classes) for the model of the game. i.e. the engine. (I may even put a cellular automaton engine on github).

Anyway, I presume you have looked into how the game of life works?

**Size of "world"**

The first thing you'll have to decide is how big you want to make the "world" in your app. I would suggest going for a finite size over an infinite size as it makes it orders of magnitude less complex.

**Model**

You'll need to store your cells in some sort of data structure. This could be a 2D array or something else. My initial version was a 2D array of bool values (true = alive, false = dead).

**Counting Neighbours**

You'll need a way of counting the number of alive neighbours for each cell.

**Iterating a generation**

Once you have all the above you should then be able to use these to advance your map by one generation.

Like I said, start with the data model and basic functions before you do anything visual for the app.

Once you've done that you can start working out how to display your model.

It's not a simple task and you may well have around "one thousand" lines of code at the end for you whole project.

The best way though is to dive in and just try and write it.